# Sorting descending by month string and ascending by week string

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column used for data validation drop down in the following format:

```
M01 W01 random strings
M01 W02 random strings
M01 W03 random strings
M02 W01 random strings
M02 W02 random strings
M02 W03 random strings
```

M=Month, W=Week

Right now I have column sorted by descending so most recent Month is on top:

```
M02 W03 random strings
M02 W02 random strings
M02 W01 random strings
M01 W03 random strings
M01 W02 random strings
M01 W01 random strings
```

Is there a way to also sort it so Weeks are ascending:

```
M02 W01 random strings 
M02 W02 random strings
M02 W03 random strings
M01 W01 random strings
M01 W02 random strings
M01 W03 random strings
```

I think regextract "M00" into one range, then use it to query sort original column but can't seem to get it to work:

=query({original column; regextract M00} , "select Col1, order by Col2 desc"}

EDIT: NVM I'm an idiot, all I had to do was replace ; with , in query{}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not regular `sort` function?

`=SORT(A:C,1,0,2,1)`

[image]

**Edit**

In case it was 1 column, use `regex` first:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
SORT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(M\d{2}) (W\d{2}) (.*)")),1,0,2,1)
),,2^50))`

`transpose` and `query` part is to join text back:

```
M02 W01 random strings
M02 W02 random strings
M02 W03 random strings
M01 W01 random strings
M01 W02 random strings
M01 W03 random strings
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, "M0 W03 str" is a single string in 1 column, so I need to regextract out month into second column for two level sorting.

=sort({original column; regextract M00} ,1,0,2,1)

 makes 2 columns, but I can filter just the first column. That's actually a better solution since query doesn't work on excel. Thank you!